# Magento 2.2 REST API Add Item to cart issue

Tags: cart, api, rest-api

i have an issue with **Magento ver. 2.2.0-dev** i'm trying to create a cart and insert a product for a logged user, with the magento 2 rest api, but when i try to insert a product into the cart (already correctly created) it seems doesn't work and respond with this error:

```
  "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
  "parameters": {
    "fieldName": "cartId",
    "fieldValue": null
  },
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Create a cart with get rest/V1/carts/mine
- Call the rest api for
     insert product in the cart with the correct token of the user at       rest/V1/carts/mine/items
- Headers: Authorization Bearer + [TOKEN]
- Body: cartItem: testing (sku of the product); qty: 1

**Expected Result**

- a 200 status and the json of the cart

**Actual Result**

```
{
  "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
  "parameters": {
    "fieldName": "cartId",
    "fieldValue": null
  },
```

How can i solve?? it's a bug or i forgot something? i've seen a lot of thread but no one can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!**

In postman, **we was selecting 'form-data'**, but **you have to select 'raw'** and insert a json object like this:

```
{
  "cart_item": {
    "quote_id": 5,
    "sku": "testing2",
    "qty": 1
  }
}
```

that should work! hope it helps.

Comment: <route url="/V2/order/:orderId" method="GET">
        <service class="Custom\Test\Api\OrderDetailsRepositoryInterface" method="getOrderDetails"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>

i using this . then geeting same issue

"message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "orderId",
        "fieldValue": null
    },

how to pass row data???